# SQL : 3 tables with select columns from 2 tables and sum on one column

Tags: sql

**Tbl1**

```
fld1 fld12 fld3 fld4
```

**Tbl2**

```
fld5 fld6 fld7
```

**Tbl3**

```
fld8 fld9 fld10 fld11 fld12 fld13
```

Query:

```
select fld8, fld11, fld12, sum(fld3), fld4
from tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
where fld1=fld5 and fld2=fld6 and fld7=fld8
```

Query is not running. I have used joins but sum is not working. Query with `fld3` will work but not `sum(fld3)`. Please help.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some database engines require that you specify a group by when using aggregates (sum, count avg etc)

```
select fld8, fld11, fld12, sum(fld3), fld4
from tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
where fld1=fld5 and fld2=fld6 and fld7=fld8
GROUP BY fld8, fld11, fld12, fld4
```

or written a different way

```
select fld8, fld11, fld12, sum(coalesce(fld3,0)), fld4
from tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 on fld1=fld5 and fld2=fld6
INNER JOIN tbl3 on  fld7=fld8
GROUP BY fld8, fld11, fld12, fld4
```

now both assume that you have records in ALL 3 tables.  If that's not the case, you may need to use outer joins and either coalesce on the sum field or nvl depending on engine.

So maybe...

```
SELECT fld8, fld11, fld12, sum(coalesce(fld3,0)), fld4
FROM  tbl1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 on fld1=fld5 and fld2=fld6
LEFT JOIN tbl3 on  fld7=fld8
GROUP BY fld8, fld11, fld12, fld4
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not used Group by and Instead using Order by. I have framed the query using LEFT JOIN and works like charming.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have `group by`

```
select fld8, fld11, fld12, sum(fld3), fld4 
from tbl1, tbl2, tbl3 where fld1=fld5 and fld2=fld6 and fld7=fld8 
group by fld8, fld11, fld12, fld4
```

Otherwise how will the `sum` function work?

Comment: They don't *have* to have `GROUP BY`, Depending on the desired results they might need `sum(fld3) OVER ()`. Depends what they are hoping `sum(fld3)` is going to return.